# Why does getJSON not wait for response?

Tags: jquery, json

I have a function that I want to return an array when the results are completed. I want the JSON data to return before exiting the function. How do I make the make the function wait for the JSON data to return before exiting the function?

```
function callback(results) {
       console.log("callback");
       return results;
    }

function UserNameMatchResults(userName) {
       if (userName == '') return;
       var results = [];
       $.getJSON('json_data.php', { method: 'matchUsers', userName: userName }, function(data) {
          $.each(data, function(key, value) {
             console.log("Name Match >>> " + value.user_id);
             results.push(value.user_id);
          });
          callback(results);
       });
    }
```

I've also tried `response.when` and `response.done` and the function `UserNameMatchResults` does not wait for the JSON data to return.

```
function callback(results) {
       console.log("callback");
       return results;
    }

    function CertMatchResults(certName) {
       if (certName == '') return;
       var results = [];
       var response = $.getJSON('json_data.php', { method: 'matchCerts', certName: certName }, function(data) {
          $.each(data, function(key, value) {
             console.log("Cert Match >>> " + value.user_id);
             results.push(value.user_id);
          });
       });
       response.done(function(results) {
          callback(results);
       });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not closing properly your brackets!

```
function UserNameMatchResults(userName) {
   if (userName == '') return;
   var results = [];
   $.getJSON('json_data.php', { method: 'matchUsers', userName: userName }, function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(key, value) {
         console.log("Name Match >>> " + value.user_id);
         results.push(value.user_id);
      )}//HERE
      callback(results);
   });
}
```

Comment: I removed the semi colon and the method exits before waiting for the JSON data to return.

Comment: No, you inverted the parenthesis and the bracket.

Comment: This still does not wait for the JSON to come back before exiting the function `UserNameMatchResults`

Comment: This function is called from another function which has other function calls after it and the function calls after it are fired before the data is returned.